# Cannot assign value of type 'UserDrink.Type' to type 'UserDrink?' Error

Tags: swift

I define my object as empty as so:

```
var userDrinkObject : UserDrink?
```

I then assign to it later with:

```
self.userDrinkObject = UserDrink
```

It throws the error:

> Cannot assign value of type 'UserDrink.Type' to type 'UserDrink?'

Why would this be the case? Seems ok to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to assign the class type to the property. You want to assign an instance of the class to the property.

Try:

```
self.userDrinkObject = UserDrink()
```

This assumes you have an `init` method that takes no parameters. Fill in the parentheses as needed if you have other `init` methods.